# What are some common ways to add variable descriptions with equations?

Tags: math-mode, equations, notes

I'm looking for a good way to add variable descriptions immediately following equations.  In plain text, it might look something like this:

*r_p = a(1-e)*

where *a* is semi-major axis

(space) *e* is eccentricity (perhaps *e* is neatly aligned with *a*)

Further, I'm interested in placing this equation and the descriptions inside of a list:

```
\begin{itemize}
\item Periapse
    \begin{itemize}
    \item The point of closest approach to the foci
    \[r_p = a(1-e)\]
    (variable descriptions)
    \end{itemize}
\item Apoapse
    \begin{...
      ...
\end{itemize}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand{\where}[1]{where~\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}>{$}c<{$}@{ }l@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item Periapse
    \begin{itemize}
        \item The point of closest approach to the foci
        \[r_p = a(1-e)\]
        \where{a & is semi-major axis \\e & is eccentricity}
    \end{itemize}
    \item Apoapse
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]